# php как изменить картинка музыка telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot, аудио

меня надо поменять картинку музыка я сделала так но не поменяется

```php
if($text=="/test"){
bot('sendAudio',[
'chat_id'=>$chid,
'audio'=>new CURLFile("audio/$arnom_-_$qunom.mp3"),
'thumb'=>"https://website.ru/image/1.jpg",
'caption'=>"$arnom",
]);
}
```